# How can I check if a sequence of values is correctly ordered?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, syntactic-sugar

I have many `Action` objects with a property `long Timestamp`. I want to do something like this:

```
Assert.IsTrue(a1.Timestamp < a2.Timestamp < a3.Timestamp < ... < an.Timestamp);
```

Unfortunately, this syntax is illegal. Is there a built-in way or a extension\LINQ\whatever way to perform this?

Note that it's target for a unit test class, so get crazy. I don't care about performance, readability and etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
private static bool isValid(params Action[] actions)
{
  for (int i = 1; i < actions.Length; i++)
    if (actions[i-1].TimeStamp >= actions[i].TimeStamp)
      return false;
  return true;
}

Assert.IsTrue(isValid(a1,a2,...,an));
```

Comment: I'm going with this one because it allow me to know where it went wrong by changing `return false;` to `return i;`

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
Action[] actions = { a1, a2, a3, ... an };
Assert.IsTrue
  (actions.Skip(1)
          .Zip(action, (next, prev) => prev.Timestamp < next.Timestamp)
          .All(b => b));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool InOrder(params long[] data)
{
  bool output = true;

  for (int i = 0; i <= data.Count-1;i++)
  {
    output &= data[i] < data[i + 1];
  }
  return output;
}
```

I used a for loop as this guarantees the order of the iteration, what a foreach loop wouldn't do.

Answer (score 1):

by assuming `actions` is a List or array:

```
actions.Skip(1).Where((x,index)=>x.Timespan > actions[i].Timespan).All(x=>x)
```

Comment: I've just wrote a similar one but with ternary operator instead of Skip. Skip is MUCH better. BTW, i think `Count() == 0` is better than `.All(x=>x)'.

Comment: @HuBeZa, yes you can use Count() = 0, I don't know what's the exact running time of Count() (may be n) if is so All is better, because of this I didn't wrote Count() :)